# In R - obtain all commit dates & sha values from *public* repository of an R package in GitHub

Tags: r, api, github

I am interested in getting, from R, all commits times, and sha values from public GitHub repositories (of R packages). For example, a list of all times and sha values for all commits in github::crsh/papaja

My current solution involves going through Github's API
https://api.github.com/repos/crsh/papaja/commits?per_page=100

But it has some drawbacks. It sets limits of 100 results per page max, so one needs to loop to get more, ti is a bit slow, maybe 2 sec per set of 100 hits. And github seems to impose a limit on number of queries.

I wonder if there is a more direct and speedy way to do this.

I have looked at API documentation and git2r and I don't think this is something that is discussed (most documentation seems to be about using git for one's on repository, but this is about querying public repositories)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no other way, the "100 per page" limit is not adjustable.

You can get them slowly then keep updating them by getting the new commits only.